Accessing memory in IAR compiled firmware without IAR toolchain
I am trying to integrate a code coverage tool into the testing workflow, to have a rough understanding of code coverage using manual tests.
I have a Renesas RL78 MCU and the Firmware compiled for it with IAR toolchain.
I want to flash a firmware prepared by IAR into a target, run tests for some time and then be able to halt the target and download the certain memory region (certain array with code coverage data) to host PC.
Is there a possibility to do that without using IAR C-SPY debugger?
Note: I am currently using Renesas E2 Lite debugger to interface with target

One possibility could be to use the Debugger macros for filing any collected data during the debug session.
The IDE's Information Center comes with an example for simulating a serial port, which demonstrates how to simulate a serial port which reads the input from a file in the host.
The example serves as basis for inverting the direction where the macro would then pipe the desired memory contents to a text file for later analysis.
You can find more information here, in the IAR debugger's user manual: https://netstorage.iar.com/FileStore/STANDARD/001/002/682/rl78/doc/EWRL78_DebuggingGuide.ENU.pdf#page=301

Would you be able to share where in IDE Information Center have you found the example you are mentioning? As I cannot find it

It should be available within the Information Center:  "Help/Information Center/Product explorer/Advanced Debugging/Simulating a serial port".
